# how to estimate gas limit when using web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction

Tags: web3js, gas-estimate

I am using web3 to transfer tokens by using web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.

When I am setting the parameter rawTx like

> > var rawTx = {
> >
> > ```
> >      "from"      : walletbase,       
> >      "nonce"     : value, 
> >      "gasPrice"  : web3.utils.toHex(2000000000), //2 gwei
> >       "gasLimit"  : estimateGas,
> >       "to"        : contractAddr,     
> >       "value"     : "0x00",
> >       "data"      : data,
> >       // "chainId"    : 3
> >   }
> > ```

I want to set the gasLimit dynamically. 
I tried to calculate the gasLimit by using web3.eth.estimateGas like:

> web3.eth.estimateGas({
>
> ```
>           to  : toAddress,
>           data: data
>           })
> ```

But the value is lower than need. I always got error like:

> > Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:

Do you have better way to calculate the gasLimit? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include nonce field in estimate gas calculation.

```
 web3.eth.estimateGas({
     "from"      : walletbase,       
     "nonce"     : value, 
     "to"        : contractAddr,     
     "data"      : data
})
```

Answer (score 2):

So you need to transfer tokens and estimate gas for that. If you are using web 1.0.x, you have more cleaner solution.

Generally, the gas estimate is correct but may be you didn't get the `data` param correctly. TRy the code below from [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id28). If this doesn't help. Post your code as well so that problem can be replicated.

```
// using the promise
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).estimateGas({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.then(function(gasAmount){
    ...
})
.catch(function(error){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pinank's a good solution, but in my case I discovered it worked once and then was 'reverted' subsequently. After spending many hours troubleshooting, I decided to change the destination address and that ended the revert error.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly for me all the time..

```
   var gasprice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
   gasprice = Math.round(gasprice * 1.2);// to speed up 1.2 times..

  var buyItem = contractInstances.methods.method1(objId)
  var gas_estimate = await buyItem.estimateGas({ from: account })
  gas_estimate = Math.round(gas_estimate * 1.2); 

  buyItem
      .send({
        from: account,
        gas: web3.utils.toHex(gas_estimate), 
        gasPrice:  web3.utils.toHex(gasprice),
      })
```